# Is there any other way besides manual events for EF Core to track most recent rows of another entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-6.0

Let's say I have an entity that has these properties

User Entity

- int SchoolId      ->  PK
- Date CreatedAt    -> PK
- string UserName

And I wanted to create an additional entity that stores the 2 most recently created users for a SchoolId/CreatedAt combo Such as:

TwoRecentUsers Entity

- int ID       -> PK
- User MostRecentUser
- User SecondMostRecentUser

The solution I'm looking into follows this flow.  Create a domain event which responds to a creation of User Entity, and then configure a handler that updates the TwoRecentUsers entity.  The handler checks if the newly inserted row has a date that is more recent than either MostRecentUser's CreatedAt or SecondMostRecentUser's CreatedAt, and updates based on a few checks.

This all seems a bit manual, and I'm wondering if you could suggest any other alternative ideas for a solution in EF Core.  I've been recommended something like a materialized view, but not sure if that's a good idea, with the lack of support EF Core has for it.

Comment: The TwoRecentUsers entity looks like it can be subject to race conditions when multiple connections are creating users.

While having a query that returns the two most recent users with an index on SchoolId/CreatedAt would achieve same result without complications.

Comment: That's a point I hadn't thought about - I'll take a look into that topic.

I wanted some sort of entity that would store this data, I didn't think that was possible with just a query. The reason being is that this TwoRecentUsers entity will need to do a bit of manipulation involving other joins.